# How to serialize an object and read it into JsonNode?

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jackson

I have a simple Java object that has a String property that contains serialized java objects:

```
@Data
private class Test {
    int id;
    String data;
}
```

The data is created with

```
test.setData(mapper.writeValueAsString(anyJavaObjectThatShouldBeSerialized));
```

Then I send the Test Object to another server, where I want to deserialize the object from the data property into a JSONNode:

```
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(test.getData());
```

The problem is, that the result of readTree is a TextNode and not a JsonNode. Therefore I can not access the properties of the serialized data.

The problem might be that the serialized object is interpreted as a String because when I print it it has quotationsmarks around it:

```
"{\"id\":39,\"name\":\"Im a test value\"}"
```

How do I get a JsonNode from the String that contains serialized objects? Please note that the data can be ANY Java object, that's why I serialized it into a String.

Comment: "test.getData()" has quotation marks around it because it's a String. You are right. What's the issue?

Comment: Basically, you are trying to convert an Object to String, then String to JsonNode, then try "node.get("id").asText()" you will get the id or node.get("name").asText() to get data.

Answer (score 0):

Make a double deserialization - first deserialize the string payload to json, then deserialize the json to class, or `JsonNode` in your case.

```
public class Temp {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String payload = //your string payload;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String json = mapper.readValue(payload, String.class);
    JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(json);
  }
}
```

As you noted, the cause is that you are making double serialization - first when setting the `data` field, then again when sending data to the other server.

You can avoid this double serialization/deserialization by making `data` an object.

```
@Data
class Test {

  int id;
  Object data;
}
```

```
test.setData(anyJavaObjectThatShouldBeSerialized);
```

Like this it will be serialized like `JsonObject`.

```
{
  "id": 39,
  "name": "Im a test value"
}
```